# How to bring out all factors recursively except one particular term?

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

I want to write a function

```
keepOnly[expr_, keep_]
```

Such that

```
keepOnly[f[f2*g[g2*h[h2*keep, h1], g1], f1], keep]
```

becomes

```
f2*h2*g2*f[g[h[keep, h1], g1], f1]
```

In other words, we take all the factors out except for the term `keep`.

Comment: Are you sure that `g1` in the list of multiplicative factors is not an error? The pattern suggests that it should be `g2`.

Comment: @Shredderroy Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
exp = f[f2*g[g2*h[h2*keep, h1], g1], f1];

FixedPoint[Replace[#, a_[b_. c_, d___] /; Not[FreeQ[c, keep]] :> b a[c, d], {0, ∞}] &, exp]
```

> f2 g2 h2 f[g[h[keep, h1], g1], f1]

Alternatively,

```
FixedPoint[Replace[#, a_[b_. c_?(Not@*FreeQ[keep]), d___] :> b a[c, d], {0, ∞}] &, exp]
```

> f2 g2 h2 f[g[h[keep, h1], g1], f1]

Comment: Doesn't `ReplaceRepeated` with pretty much the same patterns also do it? `ReplaceRepeated[f[f2 * g[g2 * h[h2 * keep, h1], g1], f1], a_[b_ * c_?(Not@*FreeQ[keep]), d_] :> b * a[c, d]]`

Comment: I was a bit confused at first because the original question had `g1` as one of the multiplicative factors, not `g2`.

Comment: @Shredderroy, yes `ReplaceRepeated` also works an is simpler. It doesn't work with the pattern I had tried (`a_[b_. c_, d___]`), so I used `Replace` `FixedPoint` combination.